# GET data from Airtable using API

Tags: javascript, api, airtable

I’m new to using API’s but managed to get my data from Airtable, the problem is, it’s gets everything.

How do I target a certain column? I.e I want to get the contents of the Name column?

And secondly.

How do I check if a name exists in that column?

```
let url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/"
let api = "Bearer 12345678910"
let baseid = "12345678910"
let tableid = "/Table%203"
let fullurl = url + baseid + tableid
console.log(url + baseid + tableid)


let req = new Request(fullurl)

req.method = "GET"

req.headers={
  "Authorization":api,
  "Content-Type":"application/json",
  "fields":"Name"
}



   response= await req.loadString()

   console.log(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Airtable's REST API allows you to limit the number of fields you fetch using the `field` query parameter.  You currently have `fields: "Name"` as a header in your request, not in the URL itself.

You can modify `fullURL` to be:

```
let fields = "?fields%5B%5D=Name";
let fullUrl = url + baseid + tableid + fields;
```

The API will return a list of all records, but only include the `Name` field in them.  If you want to include multiple fields, you add an "&" and repeat the format.  For example, if I wanted to include the Type field as well:

```
let fields = "?fields%5B%5D=Name&fields%5B%5D=Type"
```

The `%5B%5D` is the URL encoded format for `[]`.

Answer (score -1):

In most APIs, you are not able to get a single field. GraphQL solves this problem perfectly, because, with it, you decide which fields (columns) you want to retrieve.

Comment: Oh, that’s a shame. Not sure I can use GraphQL as I am using iOS shortcuts and a program called scriptable on the iPad so don’t think there’s a way to install it

Comment: Do you have a terminal there?

Comment: Anyway, it is the REST API, so GraphQL won't work. You can of course get all fields and filter it on the frontend side to have only `Name`.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Can you show me what exactly do you receive from the request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226825/discussion-between-velrin-black-and-dan).